# C# LINQ, script with JOIN and GroupBy throwing exception

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I am working on the LINQ script that is on .NET CORE 5 platform along with Entity Framework Core 5.0.8
The script simple left join along with group but getting exception, If don't apply group then I can see result... not sure what I am missing from the puzzle

exception

```
could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'
```

### code

```
var a1 =
  (from site in db.Sites
  join machine in db.Machines on site.SiteId equals machine.SiteId into sm
  from siteMachines in sm.DefaultIfEmpty()
  where site.SiteId == SiteId
  group siteMachines by site into groupedSiteMachines
  select new
      {
       listedSite = groupedSiteMachines.Key,
       SiteMachines = groupedSiteMachines.FirstOrDefault() == null? null : groupedSiteMachines
      }
  ).ToList() ;
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors. It would be more useful to include the stacktrace as text.

Comment: it is group by site and not site.SiteId

Comment: @Toxic - Please replace the image with the full text. You're missing what the exception actually is.

Comment: I have update error could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

Comment: @Toxic - Does that error message not give you the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **.NET 5**, `GroupBy` isn't translated to `SQL` query and you should use `AsEnumerable` or `.ToList` before `GroupBy` statement.

First you should read data from the `SQL` without any `GroupBy` statement and when data receive in your memory, use the `GroupBy`.

[Microsoft Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/breaking-changes?toc=/dotnet/core/compatibility/toc.json&bc=/dotnet/breadcrumb/toc.json#some-queries-with-correlated-collection-that-also-use-distinct-or-groupby-are-no-longer-supported)

Comment: Thanks it did work, but don't understand why EF CORE 5.0 change behaviour on Group, I was able to group record before set to ToList()

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get first element of grouped items in LINQ to Entities. Consider to rewrite query in the following way:

```cs
var query = 
    from site in db.Sites
    where site.SiteId == SiteId
    from siteMachines in db.Machines.Where(machine => site.SiteId == machine.SiteId)
        .Take(1)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        listedSite = site,
        SiteMachines = siteMachines
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail, however I did and it worked.. I am reading content and it seems there is different expectation on how to use Group By in Entity Framework Core 5

Comment: You do not need grouping here. And grouping is still has serious limitations in EF Core. EF Core 6 should support your syntax.

Answer (score 1):

So you have `Sites` and `Machines`, and there is a one-to-many relation between Sites and Machines: every Site has zero or more Machines on it, and every Machine is on exactly one Site, namely the Site that the foreign key SiteId refers to.

It seems to me, that you have a value siteId, and you want the Site with this value for primary key and all Machines on this Site.

Whenever you have a one-to-many relation, like Schools with their zero or more Students, Customers with their zero or more Orders, or in your case, Sites with their Machines, consider to use one of the overloads of [Queryable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin?view=net-5.0)

```
int siteId = 42;

var siteWithItsMachines = dbContext.Sites

    // keep only the site with siteId
    .Where(site => site.Id == siteId)

    // To get the Machines on each Site, do a GroupJoin:
    .GroupJoin(dbContext.Machines,

    site => site.Id              // from each Site take the primary key
    machine => machine.SiteId,   // from each Machine take the foreign key

    // parameter resultSelector: from every Site with all Machines on this Site
    // make one new object:
    (site, machinesOnThisSite) => new
    {
        // Select the Site properties that you plan to use:
        Id = site.Id,
        Name = site.Name,
        Location = site.Location,
        ...

        Machines = machinesOnThisSite.Select(machine => new
        {
            // select the Machine properties that you plan to use:
            Id = machine.Id,
            Type = machine.Type,
            ...

            // not needed, you already got the value
            // SiteId = machine.SiteId,
        })
        .ToList(),
    });
```

For efficiency I don't select the complete Site nor the complete Machine, but only the properties that I plan to use.